# See all hostnames on a given docker network?

Tags: docker, docker-network

Given a docker network, is it possible to list all the visible containers and their hostnames on it? I have a few docker-compose files with a custom defined network like so:

`docker-compose-1.yaml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  service-1:
    ..

networks:
  master-network:
    external: true
    name: master-network
```

`docker-compose-2.yaml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  service-2:
    ..

networks:
  master-network:
    external: true
    name: master-network
```

I would ideally like to a command like:

```
$ docker network list-hosts --network=master-network

# desired output:
service-1
service-2
```

Use case is I'm debugging an nginx reverse proxy issue on this network, I'd like to verify everything I expect to be visible is indeed visible, and also if I have any unexpected spelling issues.

Answer (score 0):

The best I have currently is a combination of:

```
docker inspect network_name
```

which will show a bunch of container ids/names under the `containers` key.

From there you could look up

```
docker inspect container_id/name
```

and get the hostnames possible under `NetworkSettings.Networks.[network_name].Aliases`, I think.

Could write a script to loop and parse through these, but wondering if there's a more straightforward command provided within docker.

Comment: I don't think there's a better approach than this.  If you're okay with only the primary `Name` of each container, that is under the container ID under `Containers`, and you could use `jq` or the `--format` option to get that one name out.